# css seems missing when adding rows in html

Tags: html, css

Im using form:form to bind each input (java spring).  I have a set of default rows in the html

```
<div class="del-form-group" id="itemRow-${cnt.index}">
    <form:input type="text" path="somepath" id="somepath" name="somepath" class="form-control del-input text-center del-input-text-item prodDate" style="width:10%;" disabled="true"/>
-- more input but will omit as redundant and the same except for path,id and name
</div>
```

and the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

The jquery to add a new row

```
    $('#itemRow-' + currentRow).after('<div class="del-form-group" id="itemRow-'+i+'">'
            +'<input type="text" id="somepath" name="somepath" class="form-control del-input text-center del-input-text-item prodDate" >'
            -- more input but will omit as redundant and the same except for path,id and name
    +'</div>');
```

I don't have issue adding the rows and it works perfectly but the css seems to be not loading properly.  Below is the screenshot

[image]

From here you can see the added rows are all squeezed together even though i use the same class when I added the rows.  Any idea why?

```
.del-input {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: calc(.5em + .75rem + 7px);
  border: 1px solid #d1d3e2;
  font-size:14px;
 }

.del-input-text-item {
  padding-right: 0rem;
  padding-left: 0rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the html-structure from the screenshot? It seems like there is something missing or too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix.  Issue is the

```
margin-right: -1px;
```

Seems it cant be read negative value when adding rows.  Instead I use

```
margin-left: 2px;
```

and the added rows are now properly aligned with the existing rows.